# Find the default value of javaMaxHeapSize in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I know i can do this ([reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html)):

```
android {
  ...
  dexOptions {
    maxProcessCount 4 // this is the default value
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
  }
}
```

But how can i know the default/current value of javaMaxHeapSize ?

My platforms is Fedora 21 and below:

```
Android Studio 2.1.2
Build #AI-143.2915827, built on May 26, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_74-b02 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you meant with:

> What is the default value of javaMaxHeapSize?

If you want to know the default value of `javaMaxHeapSize` property in `dexOptions`, the value is `null`.

If you haven't specified it, this task can demonstrate it:

```
task maxSize << {
    println("Java max heap size is: ${project.android.dexOptions.getJavaMaxHeapSize()}")
}
```

If you want to know your JVM max heap size instead (I think you wanted to know this), it's a JVM argument that can change depending on your machine.

Quoting `Oracle` documentation:

> **maximum heap size:**
>
> Smaller of 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB.
>   Before J2SE 5.0, the default maximum heap size was 64MB. You can
>   override this default using the -Xmx command-line option.

You can check it executing this UNIX command in your terminal (as you said, you are using `Fedora`):

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MaxHeapSize
```

The value is expressed in bytes.

Comment: That unix command would be the JVM on the computer, not on the Android device, which I believe the question is asking for

Comment: @cricket_007 mmh, the property "javaMaxHeapSize" change the JVM args on the computer, not on the Android device..

Comment: Right, I was just curious why you mentioned the Fedora piece

Comment: @cricket_007 I mentioned Fedora 21 because the command changes on a not Unix system. By the way, if the OP question was another, my answer will be useless so I'll delete it

Comment: I think the Gradle task is the correct answer, no need to delete unless stated otherwise